# I want to check with my account team regarding payment processing, how to ask?

Tags: grammaticality, subcontinental-english

I have to ask one of the account team members, if today they are going to provide payment.

How can I ask them, I want to know the correct English sentence?

I have prepared some sentences, can anyone clarify which is correct or not?

1. I just want to know if the payment would be processed today?
2. I just want to know if today you will process the payment?
3. May I know today if you are going to process the payment?

Comment: If you think it is so but just want to make sure, the polite expression would be "_Can you confirm_ that the payment will be processed today?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you feedback on your three suggestions, your verb tenses need adjusting:

> I just want to know that [the] payment *would be process* [will be processed] today? [no question mark needed]
>
> I just want to know that *today will you be process* [you will be processing] the payment [today]? [no question mark]
>
> May I know *today are you process* [if you are processing] the payment today?

Comment: Having looked through the guidelines for using this site, I can't find an adequate explanation for why answers like this are getting downvoted. This is the third time it's happened, with no explanation. Sorry, but I'm beginning to feel really peeved about it.

Comment: I've just downvoted a similar question, Sandy, because it was given to a question I felt should clearly be close-voted. Someone else has downvoted here. I can understand why you feel peeved, when they give no feedback. But I too feel that the question should not be endorsed by any answers. This question does not pinpoint an aspect of grammar that the OP needs explaining, but essentially asks for either proofreading (_Point out **any** errors in the following_) or writing advice (_Which of the following sentences is the best?_) The correct procedure, I feel, is to close-vote.

Comment: I don't personally believe in downvoting answers to questions that should be closed. Just because a question should be closed doesn't mean that an answer to it is bad. (In fact, I entirely object to the practice of downvoting answers on that basis.) In general, however, the problem with this type of answer is that it's subjective. There are many different way of *correcting* something (assuming it's wrong in the first place). A *good* answer will explain *why* it's wrong—and provide at least a few alternative corrections.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications Edwin and Jason. I'd assumed that the downvote was because I'd given a poor answer (which was what I'd assumed the downvoting system is for). I think that if downvotes are going to be used for purposes that have nothing to do with the content of the answer, it brings into question the loss of points that they incur.